# How do i access a shared calendar using EWS Managed API

Tags: exchangewebservices

How can retrieve only shared calendar using Exchange EWS API.

How can i know which calendar is shared using Exchange EWS API.

Comment: Firstly i call all my calendar by using below code         FolderView fvFolderView = new FolderView(1000);
                fvFolderView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;
                SearchFilter sfSearchFilter = new SearchFilter.IsEqualTo(FolderSchema.FolderClass, "IPF.Appointment");

 FindFoldersResults ffoldres = service.FindFolders(new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, "email@address"), sfSearchFilter, fvFolderView);
           Now i get 3 calendar include one shared calendar.  Need to Find shared calendar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just specify the calendar, which you want to acces in your `FolderId`.

```
FolderId folderIdFromCalendar = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Calendar, "sharedInbox@example.com");
```

You can then use the `folderIdFromCalendar` for retrieving the calendar items, you want, e.g.:

```
FindItemsResults<Item> appointments = ExchangeServive.FindItems(folderIdFromCalendar, ItemView);
```

Remember that the program has to be run in the context of a user, which the mailbox is shared with.

## Update:

If you happen to know the `FolderId`, you can just check, if the current user has access to this calendar by performing this code:

As above, you will need to initialize a `FolderId`:

```
FolderId folderIdFromCalendar = new FolderId("AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS1kNjE0LWU1ZmQtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADJRMtiupYBUGD‌​cKdcqUrr3AEA1/sqwbrw‌​UEeFM0Mc+UBFoQAAABzk‌​m1sAAAA=");
```

After that, try the following code:

```
if (folderIdFromCalendar != null)
    {
        try
        {
            ItemView cView = new ItemView(1000);
            FindItemsResults<Item> appointments = service.FindItems(folderIdFromCalendar, cView);
            int count = appointments.TotalCount; //just an example of some random action on the folder calendar
        }
        catch (ServiceResponseException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The specified calendar was not shared with you. \n" + ex);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The specified calendar ID could not be linked to a calendar folder.");
    }
```

## Another Update:

```
if (folderIdFromCalendar != null)
    {
        if (folderIdFromCalendar.Mailbox.ToString().ToLower() == "your-Mailadress".ToLower())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The folder you specified is your own");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ItemView cView = new ItemView(1000);
                FindItemsResults<Item> appointments = service.FindItems(folderIdFromCalendar, cView);
                int count = appointments.TotalCount; //just an example of some random action on the folder calendar
                Console.WriteLine("You have been given access to this mailbox. Its owner is: " + folderIdFromCalendar.Mailbox.ToString()); //if you need to know, whos mailbox you are accessing right now
            }
            catch (ServiceResponseException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The specified calendar was not shared with you. \n" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The specified calendar ID could not be linked to a calendar folder.");
    }
```

## Last Update:

I have googled quite a bit now and found something that worked for me. But to be perfectly honest, I don't understand everything, which is going on in the following code:

```
FolderId folderIdFromCalendar = new FolderId("AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS1kNjE0LWU1ZmQtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADJRMtiupYBUGD‌​cKdcqUrr3AEA1/sqwbrw‌​UEeFM0Mc+UBFoQAAABzk‌​m1sAAAA=");
    Folder folderFromCalendar = Folder.Bind(service, folderIdFromCalendar);

    AlternateId aiAlternateid = new AlternateId(IdFormat.EwsId, folderFromCalendar.Id.UniqueId, "random@mailadress.com");
    AlternateIdBase aiResponse = service.ConvertId(aiAlternateid, IdFormat.EwsId);

    var mailbox = ((AlternateId)aiResponse).Mailbox;

    if (folderFromCalendar != null)
    {
        if (mailbox.ToString().ToLower() == "your-Mailadress".ToLower())
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The folder you specified is your own");
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                ItemView cView = new ItemView(1000);
                FindItemsResults<Item> appointments = service.FindItems(folderIdFromCalendar, cView);
                int count = appointments.TotalCount; //just an example of some random action on the folder calendar
                Console.WriteLine("You have been given access to this mailbox. Its owner is: " + mailbox.ToString());
            }
            catch (ServiceResponseException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("The specified calendar was not shared with you. \n" + ex);
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("The specified calendar ID could not be linked to a calendar folder.");
    }
```

I don't understand, how the string "random@mailadress.com" affects anything in that program, but the syntax needs a string there.

Comment: I dont know the user email id for example het i don't know the email id "sharedInbox@example.com"       I am working in C# and try to know the shared calendar in my account.

Comment: This will most likely not possible, as you have to give EWS some kind of information, where to retrieve the items from.

Comment: So according to you, there is no way to find shared calendar in our account ?

Comment: In my perception, EWS can't just print out a list of calendars, which are shared with a specific account. For all I know, you have to know, which calendar you want to access, before performing any actions in EWS. Do you use an exchange online server or are you hosting on-prem?

Comment: I have calendar Id like   AQMkADAwATM3ZmYAZS1kNjE0LWU1ZmQtMDACLTAwCgAuAAADJRMtiupYBUGDcKdcqUrr3AEA1/sqwbrwUEeFM0Mc+UBFoQAAABzkm1sAAAA=     I want to know that this is shared calendar or not ?

Comment: I have updated my answer so that it should fit your needs

Comment: Problem remain same.   If i pass calendar Id which shared with me it's return me appointment.      If i pass calendar id which is create by me OR my default calendar id,    It's return me appointment.    SO how is differentiate  between them which one is shared.

Comment: I have updated it yet another time. Please, for your next question on this board, try to provide more info from the beginning, so others don't have to write code, which does meet the requirements, of what you described, but not of what you want.

Comment: I have updated my question      I have use you code but folderIdFromCalendar.Mailbox is NULL.